# Using one or two dimensional arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vector

I have a couple of  basic questions about using arrays in VBA, which I have not found  the answer to.

Firstly, is there a way to specify a one dimensional row vector in Excel VBA?

I am new to using arrays in Excel VBA, and have been defining row and column vectors as two dimensional arrays, as in the examples below

```
'Define a Local Row Vector
ReDim aArray(1 to iCntRows, 1 to 1)

'Define a Local Column Vector
ReDim aArray(1 to 1, 1 to iCntCols)
```

So secondly, is this best practice?  Should I be using a one dimensional array instead?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Why on Earth you want to use 2D array for ONE row/column?

Comment: because Excel ranges are 2-dimensional

Comment: Thanks Charles.  I think that is why I started using them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you intend to copy the array to a range, like

```
Range(somerange) = aArray
```

Then , yes, use 2d arrays

Comment: Thanks Chris, I often read a sheet range into an array, manipulate it and write it back to the sheet. However, I am also using 2d arrays in procedures that just read the range from the sheet, to manipulate other arrays.  Would you store these as 1d arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the transpose function to convert from a 2d array.

```
new_array = Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A2:A100").Value)
```

where new_array is a 1d array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub tt()

    Const SZ As Long = 1000
    Dim arr(), x

    ReDim arr(1 To SZ)
    For x = 1 To SZ
        arr(x) = x
    Next x

    'add to sheet (as a row)
    Sheet1.Range("a1").Resize(1, SZ).Value = arr

    'add to sheet (as a column)
    'note there is an upper limit when using transpose of around 65k
    Sheet1.Range("a5").Resize(SZ, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, would you mind adding some comments to explain what your procedure is doing?  I am not sure what to learn from this.  Thanks, Tim

Comment: You asked about using 1D arrays. My example was just to illustrate how they can be used, an what to watch out for (that a 1D array needs to be transposed before it can be assigned to a column-shaped range)